# Is Firebase affecting my Jquery/Semantic-UI Dropdown?

Tags: jquery, firebase, drop-down-menu, semantic-ui

I am working on a project in which I have a Semantic-UI/jQuery Dropdown. I have the exact same code on CodePen and on my computer. But, the CodePen sample works, and the computer sample doesn't work (when I run firebase serve or when I deploy).

The only difference between the two files is that one includes Firebase. Could Firebase be affecting my project? Or am I doing something wrong? I initialized the dropdown with jQuery, I included it in Semantic-UI, and **it works in CodePen.** What am I doing wrong? I initialized my dropdown like so, which I know works because it works in CodePen:

```
$('.ui.dropdown')
  .dropdown({
  on: 'hover',
  action: 'nothing'
})
;
```

I have confirmed that other parts of the JS and CSS work.
A link to my CodePen: https://codepen.io/nebrelbug/pen/aVEOZp

I suggest just looking at the CodePen, but if you really want the code is here:

My head looks like this:

```
<title>Head</title>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.6.2/firebase.js"></script>
<script>
  // Initialize Firebase
  var config = {
    apiKey: "[]",
    authDomain: "[]",
    databaseURL: "[]",
    projectId: "[]",
    storageBucket: "[]",
    messagingSenderId: "[]"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/semantic-ui@2.2.13/dist/semantic.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/semantic-ui@2.2.13/dist/semantic.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/quotes.css">
<script src="/quotes.js"></script>
```

My CSS looks like this:

```
body {
    background: #e8ebef;
  }

  .ui.secondary.pointing.fixed.menu {
    border-bottom: 0px solid;
    margin-top: 5em;
  }

  .menu.toxindex, .scrolling.menu, div.ui.floating.dropdown.button {
    z-index: 999;
  }
```

Ignore the extra CSS, I deleted some stuff from the HTML but confirmed it has the same behaviour.

JS:

```
var displayName;
var email;
var uid;

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    if (user) {
      // User is signed in.
      displayName = user.displayName;
      email = user.email;
      var emailVerified = user.emailVerified;
      var photoURL = user.photoURL;
      var isAnonymous = user.isAnonymous;
      uid = user.uid;
      var providerData = user.providerData;
      $("#username").text(displayName);
      console.log("user");
      // ...
    } else {
      // User is signed out.
      // ...
      window.location.replace("login.html");
    }
  });

function signOutFromGoogle () {
    $("#username").text("Signing out...");
    firebase.auth().signOut().then(function() {
        window.location.replace("login.html");
    }).catch(function(error) {

    });
}

function showModal() {
    $('.ui.modal')
    .modal('show')
  ;
  }

  $('#dropdownly')
  .dropdown({
    on: 'hover',
    action: 'nothing'
  });
```

Again, ignore the extra stuff (including the #username write).

Comment: You might find this interesting: [link] (https://crisp.chat/blog/why-you-should-never-use-firebase-realtime-database/)